# Centos 6.9, how to install gdbus-codegen?

Tags: centos, centos6, centos6.5

I'm having a hard time trying to compile `cups-filters-1.14.0` on Centos 6. Now, after hours of installing dependencies I get this:

```
gdbus-codegen \
            --interface-prefix org.cups.cupsd \
            --c-namespace Cups \
            --generate-c-code cups-notifier \
            utils/org.cups.cupsd.Notifier.xml
make: gdbus-codegen: Command not found
make: *** [cups-notifier.c] Error 127
```

How can I install `gdbus-codegen` ?

Comment: did you install "glib2" and "glib2-devel"?

Comment: please check this : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html